# Highlighting points on matplot axis in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to highlight certain points on x axis in R matplot, but couldn't find anything online to add this highlight.

My current R code looks like:

```
matplot(tafmc[,-5], type="l", lwd=2, xlab="Read Length", ylab= "Base frequency at each position", axes=F)
axis(2)
axis(side=1,at=1:12)
legend(legend = colnames(tafmc)[-5],"topright",col=1:4, lty=1:4, lwd=2)
```

with tafmc:

```
> tafmc
               A          C          G         T        other
 [1,] 0.07750099 0.07069229 0.05263019 0.7964281 2.748438e-03
 [2,] 0.33514177 0.18633073 0.24072018 0.2377887 1.863047e-05
 [3,] 0.29248243 0.24511224 0.20211045 0.2599584 3.365314e-04
 [4,] 0.28781535 0.21744510 0.22640813 0.2682291 1.023197e-04
 [5,] 0.38658168 0.18382597 0.18121268 0.2477646 6.151013e-04
 [6,] 0.30973779 0.19046315 0.22233131 0.2765137 9.539984e-04
 [7,] 0.28136595 0.20856398 0.23399280 0.2760773 0.000000e+00
 [8,] 0.27421037 0.21245036 0.23216199 0.2811773 0.000000e+00
 [9,] 0.26470528 0.22441881 0.22949251 0.2813834 0.000000e+00
[10,] 0.30831951 0.20324602 0.22462079 0.2638137 0.000000e+00
[11,] 0.28210999 0.20171182 0.24064536 0.2755328 0.000000e+00
[12,] 0.28901716 0.20485948 0.23162141 0.2745020 0.000000e+00
```

and the current plot looks like this: 
[image: current plot]

and I want something like this(in this case, highlighting point 1 and 10 on X axis):

[image]

Is there a straightforward way to do this ? Or do I need to switch to ggplot2 for something equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add those rectangles with `rect`

```
rect(c(0.7,9.7), c(0,0), c(1.3,10.3), c(1,1), col="#DD666666", border=NA)
```

[image: Added rectangles]